# How to Programmatically Detect if computer is inside a LAN?

Tags: networking, network-programming, lan

I'm coding an application which uses the Gnutella protocol. This software may run in computers which could be in the same LAN.

If so, I want to group them together since they have faster intercommunication. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it:

1. You can nmap the subnet space to get a list of all the responding IP addresses. 
   E.g. nmap -sP 10.0.0.0/24
2. If you know the IP addresses, you can use arping. Computers in a local subnet will respond while those in another will not.

You can, of course, program a wrapper around those tools and based on the responses group the IP addresses together.

Cheers,
SS